# Upgrading GCP deep learning VM gives error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-dl-platform

I'm trying to upgrade a VM from M58 to M66 so I can use PyTorch 1.8. The upgrade button on "edit VM details" results in "this operation cannot be completed." Any idea why that might be the case and what to do when it happens?

Comment: how did you create your VM? Using Marketplace or gcloud commands? Maybe using just the Console.
Also, when you refer to "M58" you mean, memory optimized with 58 vCPUs? 
Lastly, is the VM stopped when you are trying to upgrade it?
Normally there is more information in the logs, you may want to check there and share the info here.

Comment: It was created on Marketplace. The M58 is the environment version currently listed. I ultimately just created a new VM and used gcloud commands to copy literally everything over to the new one. Worked out alright and seemed faster than digging through logs haha

Comment: Lol, you're right.
So, with that in mind I'll add an answer, realistically, I've noticed that GCP doesn't have an "Upgrade Marketplace Solution" documentation because it's really high dependant of the solution. So.... Check answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general terms, upgrading a Marketplace Solution is not the best approach, instead it's better to keep the solution disposable and redeploy a new version when you want, then move all your information and configurations to that new version.

This is because Marketplace solutions depend on the partners not on GCP, furthermore, GCP doesn't even have an official documentation about upgrading a Marketplace Solution (it does have [this](https://cloud.google.com/marketplace/docs/manage-deployments#managing_your_deployments) to MANAGE deployments but it doesn't talk much about upgrades).

So, you made the right choice when you decided to just deploy the new version.

Answer (score 0):

For reference please refer to Upgrade a Notebooks instance's environment [document](https://cloud.google.com/notebooks/docs/upgrade).
You can use `is-upgradeable` API endpoint to determine upgrade eligibility.

```
gcloud notebooks instances is-upgradeable <notebook-name> --location=<location>
```